# AsyncTask throwing android.view.WindowLeaked error

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have gone through similar questions here but could not fix the problem.

I KNOW i am showing progress bar after i exited the activity but i do not understand where am i wrong in my code, i am showing the progress bar in `onPreExecute` and dismissing it in `onPostExecute`.

CODE

```
private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Boolean>{

        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo nf = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(nf != null && nf.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if(urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch(MalformedURLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(IOException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th) {
            if(th == true) {
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessLogin().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                errorMSG.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            }
        }
    }
```

ERROR LOGS

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity boxyworldreseller.com.boxyworldreseller.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{322c8153 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,483} that was originally added here
                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                     at boxyworldreseller.com.boxyworldreseller.Login$NetCheck.onPreExecute(Login.java:92)
                     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:591)
                     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:539)
                     at boxyworldreseller.com.boxyworldreseller.Login.NetAsync(Login.java:77)
                     at boxyworldreseller.com.boxyworldreseller.Login$3.onClick(Login.java:68)
                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: @Selvin i have had enough of search, i see same questions but how do i show dialog before leaving activity, in fact i am not leaving activity at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if(!isFinishing() && this != null){
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
}
        }
```

Before Showin progress dialog check this two condition if you are using activity else if you are using fragment then use like below:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if(!getActivity().isFinishing() && getActivity()!= null)
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i added this condition, no change, same error i get